# JasperReports: Update several "slaves" report when a "master" report is updated

Tags: jasper-reports, updates

I was wondering if it was possible to force the update of several report  when I update one of them (update master -> update slave1, slave2 and slave3) and if it was a good practise.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[Explication Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2J4g1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to approximately do it, I will give you a sample case :

In this sample, we want to have a "master report" and a "slave report" which will copy the content of the master.

1) Build the master report (just a classic text field inside) and publish it on jasperserver

2) Build the slave report, put only a subreport in it with this expression "repo:/path_to_your_master_folder/master_report_files/main_jrxml" then publish it

3) Check with the main_jrxml file of your slave report that you have a subreport with the good expression in it (can be buggy sometimes)

-> Now when you update the master report and publish it again (change the static text for example), the slave report is updated

WARNING : This method doesn't work if you have external config (images, input controls, ...) so be prepared to copy them with another method

Hope this will be helpfull !